# Extending solutions of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

I have a following exercise: 
Prove that every solution of an equation $x' = \sin(x^2+t^2) + 3|x|$ can be extended to all  $t$ in real numbers. 
How do I go about proving this? I know theorems stating that such extension is possible if the right-hand side is bounded, but here it clearly isn't. 
I'll be grateful for any help. :)

Comment: The bound can also be a linear function in $|x|$. This is essentially an application of the Grönwall lemma, or the idea that the exact or equation solution to a differential inequality is a bound for any function satisfying the inequality.

Comment: Answer in the spirit of the comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3917129/determining-the-largest-interval-of-definition-of-a-cauchy-problem/3917140#3917140, example with some more, but not complete, detail https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2951771/differential-equations-global-solution-on-bbb-r